# Oracle Apex send an Calender Invite as an Appointment not ICS attachment

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I would like to send a calendar invitation via Oracle Apex.
There are already many tutorials explaining how to send the calendar entry as an ICS attachment. In my case I would like to try that the recipient receives a direct invitation.
So far I have used the APEX_MAIL extension.

Here is a part of the Code i use: (That is the way i can send the Appointment as ICS Attatchment)

```
  if l_body is not null then
        l_mail_id := apex_mail.send(
            --p_to       =>  rec.creator_email,
            p_to       =>  t_an_liste,
            p_cc     => '',
            p_bcc    => '',
            --p_bcc    => '',
            p_from     => 'noreply@Sample.com', 
            p_body     => l_body,
            p_body_html => l_body,
            p_subj     => l_title);
     if rec.SHOP_name is not null then
        if rec.HYPERLINK Like '%teams.microsoft.com%' then
            v_location := 'Microsoft Teams-Besprechung';
        else
            v_location := rec.HYPERLINK;
        end if;
     l_cal_1 := APEX_MAIL_CALENDAR('Terminbuchung ('||rec.SHOP_name||')',l_body,rec.TS_OPEN,rec.TS_CLOSE,v_location,15,'N');
     apex_mail.add_attachment (p_mail_id         => l_mail_id,
                            p_attachment      => l_cal_1,
                            p_filename        => 'Termineintrag.ics',
                            --Name of the ICS file
                            p_mime_type       => 'application/hbs-ics'
                           );
     
     end if;   
        APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE;
    end if;
```

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?
Thank you!

Lukas :)

Comment: What is `APEX_MAIL_CALENDAR`? That is not part of a standard APEX installation.

Comment: Correct, APEX_MAIL_CALENDAR is a self-coded function used in our project.
By providing the needed infomations it returns a blob element containing the ICS-object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft 365, simplest way would probably be to use the Microsoft Graph API to [Create an Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). You can pass all of the information about the "event" in the meeting invite in the body of your API request (see example below).

You will need to set up the proper access in Microsoft 365 so that you can authenticate before you can use the API. You will also need to designate an owner for the event using `/me/` in the API call or using `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/` if you have the access set up properly.

```json
{
  "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does noon work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location":{
      "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"samanthab@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Samantha Booth"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
  "transactionId":"7E163156-7762-4BEB-A1C6-729EA81755A7"
}
```